Issues with awesome-notifications in Next.js: Static Import Fails at Build Time and Dynamic Import Shows No Notifications
I’m having trouble with the awesome-notifications package in my Next.js project. I’m facing two main issues:
Static Import Works but Fails at Build Time:
When I import awesome-notifications statically, it works fine during development, but it throws errors at build time. Here's the static import code:
import { AWN } from 'awesome-notifications';
Dynamic Import Works During Build but Notifications Don’t Show:
When I use dynamic import with next/dynamic, the build process completes successfully and no errors are thrown. However, the notifications do not appear on the page. Here’s the dynamic import code:
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
   const AWN = dynamic(() => import('awesome-notifications').then(mod => mod.default), { ssr: false });


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
